# Running jupyter lab in kedro project in vscode under windows not possible

Tags: visual-studio-code, kedro

On our Windows 10 machines I tried to setup kedro projects setup on Ubuntu configured for VSCode. On Ubuntu they are working just fine. However if I run `kedro jupyter lab` in the VSCode integrated terminal on Windows I get the following error:

```
[C 12:48:35.466 LabApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 12:48:35.467 LabApp] The 'kernel_spec_manager_class' trait of <jupyterlab.labapp.LabApp object at 0x000001AFD17E6B08> instance must be a type, but 'kedro.framework.cli.jupyter.SingleKernelSpecManager' could not be imported
(.venv) PS E:\gitlab\project-XXX>
```

The Python venv is located in `<project-XXX>/.venv` and the settings (`.vscode/settings.json`) adjusted for Windows to point to the right Python interpreter and venv:

```
{
    "python.venvPath": ".venv",
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

The venv has been started with `.\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` successfully. BTW: If I run `jupyter lab` in the venv it works just fine. (Despite of the fact that there is not integration with the kedro context, etc.)

Comment: Does this work with a fresh `kedro` project? What version of `kedro` are you using? Can you run `from kedro.framework.cli.jupyter import SingleKernelSpecManager` in a `python3` instance within your VSCode terminal or does that fail?

Comment: I cannot try right now, but will let you know later. The version is `Kedro, version 0.16.1`. If I run `python` and run `from kedro.framework.cli.jupyter import SingleKernelSpecManager` inside the venv importing does work. Probably it has something to do how JupyterLab is managed on windows.

Comment: We've tried to reproduce this on our side with no luck, these are the steps we followed. Can you let us know if it mirrors yours?

1. Created a venv inside project with python.exe -m venv .venv  (Python 3.7.8)
2. Activated venv
3. Installed Kedro via pip
4. Installed vscode (the latest from website)
5. Set interpreter: .venv\Scripts\python.exe
6. Created a new terminal: Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal
7. Installed jupyterlab
8. run kedro jupyter lab

Comment: The settings.json file looks like:

```
{
    "python.venvPath": ".venv",
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
} 
```