# kedro jupyter notebook in command prompt returns kedro.framework.cli.jupyter.single kernelspec manager' could not be imported"

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kedro

I have been trying to activate jupyter notebooks in a kedro context for over 24 hours now and I receive the same error all the time. I have searched around and no one seems to be able to solve this problem. I have created a jupyter_notebook_config.json as recommended by some and deleted it as recommended by others and there is no change.
I have installed ipython and run `$python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=myvenv`
this successfully installed kernelspec within my venv but still when i run

`kedro jupyter notebook`

i get the following error
`[C 08:50:49.028 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization: The 'kernel_spec_manager_class' trait of <notebook.notebookapp.NotebookApp object at 0x7fdef3120a90> instance must be a type, but 'kedro.framework.cli.jupyter.SingleKernelSpecManager' could not be imported`

Can anyone direct me on how to approach this as it is preventing me from conducting my work in jupyter.

note that `kedro jupyter` and `kedro jupyter lab` and `kedro ipython`  work just fine. The issue seems limited to notebook

I have tried

https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/issues/184
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2875
[Running jupyter lab in kedro project in vscode under windows not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195266/running-jupyter-lab-in-kedro-project-in-vscode-under-windows-not-possible)

none of these resources helped. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Hey! Which version of Kedro are you running?

Comment: this project calls for v0.17.5

Comment: So you should be able to upgrade to 0.17.7 without issue as there are no breaking changes in those releases, could you try that?

Answer (score 0):

After some time on this. My manager asked to run `jupyter --version` turns out that notebook was not installed.

while not a solution for everyone, it warrants a check to ensure that notebook is installed. Though this does not explain how i was able to access and work in notebook prior to noticing this issue